# Build speed of Binary search tree depending on order of insertions, but with same height

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a problem understanding insertion time complexity.

I was solving exercise problems about binary search tree, and am not sure about an answer to this problem.

```
Consider building two binary search trees containing integer keys from 1 to 63, inserted into the trees in the following orders. 
(a) All the odd integers in order (1, 3, 5, . . . , 63), then 32, 16, 48, then remaining even integers in order (2, 4, 6, . . . , 62).
(b) All the odd integers in order (1, 3, 5, . . . , 63), then remaining even integers in order (2, 4, 6, . . . , 62)
Which of these trees will be quicker to build?
```

What I think is

(1) Both BST will have same height after inserting odd integers.

(2) Since, during inserting any even integers, comparison with any other even integers do not exitst and (1), (a) and (b) will have same total number of comparison during tree building.

(3) Therefore, (a) and (b) building will be cost exact same time.

However, chatGPT 4 saying that (a) is faster (with some weird logic) and feeling that this question implies that one is faster and the other is slower, make me feel like I'm wrong.

Does (a) and (b) have different build time? or not?

Assume BST is implemented with nodes, each composed of 2 pointers(left child, right child) and one key, and insertion operation's pseudocode is

```
Insert(T,x){
if (T == null) T = new Node(x);
else if (x \< T.key) T.left = Insert(T.Left,x);
else T.right = Insert(T.Right,x);
return T;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct: both take the same time to build for the reasons you have given.

The first phase builds a backbone with odd nodes (a degenerate tree having only one root-to-leaf path). The second phase consists of insertions of even values, where the comparisons are only with *odd* nodes (on the "backbone"), and so it is irrelevant in which order the even values are inserted into the tree. The outcome is the same tree and the same work.